# How to run VS 2012 codedUI project solution remotely from command line?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

We have a simple codedUI test project solution of Visual Studio 2012.

VS 2012 has the Test - Run - All Tests option on its GUI.

We like to invoke that from command line for automation purpose.

Is there a way to do it and not using Test Manager at all ?

Thanks

Comment: See http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/7561/how-to-choose-between-tcm-exe-mstest-exe-and-vstest-console-exe for three programs that can run Coded UI tests from the command line

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Visual Studio Test Agent first in your remote/test machine. Then using a remote access tool such as [PsExec from PsTools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx) you use [MSTest.exe or VSTest.Console.exe to run a dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182486.aspx). You can script this in bat file on your own machine to trigger loading of test dlls to the remote machine and automated running.

However setting up a good build-test environment using Visual Studio TFS will always be a better and more integrated solution.